# Debugging lambda expressions in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, lambda

Do you know a Visual Studio 2008 Addon, which allows the debugging of Lambda expressions (in the Watch window)?

Answer (score 2):

It does not work for the same reason Edit-and-Continue does not work with methods with lambda expressions.

This is due to the fact that while it is easy to change the IL of a method at runtime (see MethodRental for more info), changing the metadata of an assembly (which creating a closure requires) is impossible without reloading it.

If C# had absolutely no side effects, this would be theoretically possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I read recently, it might be useful for you.

- [LINQ to Objects - Debugging](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/04/23/linq-to-objects-debugging.aspx)

You can also try VS2008 Expression Tree Visualizer or code your own. More information here

- [MSDN-Expression Tree Visualizer Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397975.aspx)